# Update data in CRM 2011 using Execute - UpdateRequest + soap XML

Tags: xml, soap, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to update the data in DCRM-2011 by executing query like,

```
update customers set customer_name='SUDHIL-2' where customer_id in('CU102','CU103')
```

How can I achieve this via Execute-Request UpdateRequest?
My SOAP request is as below,

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <request i:type="a:UpdateRequest" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
                <a:Parameters xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
                    <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                        <b:key>Target</b:key>
                        <b:value i:type="a:Entity">
                            <a:Attributes>                        
                                <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                                    <b:key>customer_name</b:key>
                                    <b:value i:type="a:OptionSetValue">
                                        <a:Value>SUDHIL-2</a:Value>
                                    </b:value>
                                </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>                                                            
                            </a:Attributes>
                            <a:EntityState i:nil="true"/>
                            <a:FormattedValues/>
                            <a:Id>f450b346-69e7-e411-80d4-0050568c1f85</a:Id>
                            <a:LogicalName>customers</a:LogicalName>
                            <a:RelatedEntities/>
                        </b:value>
                    </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                </a:Parameters>
                <a:RequestId i:nil="true"/>
                <a:RequestName>Update</a:RequestName>
            </request>
        </Execute>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance for your support?

Ashish Mishra

Answer (score 1):

The Update request can only target a single record. You will first need to retrieve the entities that match your criteria and then you can loop through the results and issue Update requests for each one using their ID.

Comment: Hi Josh... Thanks for answer.

That I did. But problem is where when there are 1M records than how we will do it? That's why I'm looking for the alternative.

Comment: That is the classic problem. I hope that MS adds a multiple update feature soon. Another possible alternative coming up in the latest release is to define your own primary key fields. This way you could at least issue updates directly with your own custom key without querying them first. There is also an ExecuteMultiple request that you can use to package up your updates and make less requests overall, but you are still updating each individual record. For now, I suggest multi-threaded client code and vigorous optimization. :)