# Soap request to update multiple records in Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm

We are trying to update multiple records at once in CRM, but based on the wsdl there is no direct method to do this. One approach is to update each record in the CRM by passing the CRM id of the record to be updated. However from reading the documentation, we found that there is a way to run ExecuteMultiple but unsure of how the SOAP request body would look like. The reason we need the SOAP request structure is because we are constructing the request in our PHP environment. All the documentation gives us C# code, can you please suggest the best approach to this problem?

Comment: Look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31066528/7920473

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to do updates in Dynamics that affect multiple records at once like the UPDATE command in SQL. Every update or delete or create request works on a single record.

However, you can batch these requests together into one web request by using the Batch Operations feature. Batch operations lets you group normal create/update/delete messages (or any of the other SDK messages) into a single web request.

See documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/execute-batch-operations-using-web-api

Comment: @Arun do you agree?